# How to input text in table form input using selenium java?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new in using selenium, but I'm already read a lot of documentation and some code from websites. 
I want to write weight, and height to get BMI (ideal weight).
There are 3 forms like weight form, height form (in feet) and height form (in inch).
After writing in that form, Click Button Calculate to get BMI.

I write my code like this

```
        WebElement searchForm = driver.findElement(By.tagName("form"));
        searchForm.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
        WebElement searchBox = searchForm.findElement(By.name("weight"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("200");
        WebElement searchBox1 = searchForm.findElement(By.name("height1"));
        searchBox1.sendKeys("4");
        WebElement searchBox2 = searchForm.findElement(By.name("height2"));
        searchBox2.sendKeys("22");
```

My code doesn't work, so I tried an old code like this

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/input")).sendKeys("200");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span[1]/input")).sendKeys("4");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span[2]/input")).sendKeys("22");
```

I got error "`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='weight']"}`"
I don't know why `weight` can't get after using xpath.

I read on websites, they write the code and get the input form using `driver.findElement(By.id(""));` But in this HTML code, there is no ID.

this is HTML code

```
<table style="background-color: white;" width="300" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" height="100">
    <form name="bmi"></form>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <span class="style4">Weight:</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="style3">
                    <input type="text" class="bmi_txtbx" size="4" name="weight">
                        <select class="bmi_txtbx" value="lbs" name="weightuom">
                            <option selected="" value="lbs">lbs</option>
                            <option value="kg">kg</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <span class="style4">Height:</span>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="style3">
                    <input type="text" class="bmi_txtbx" size="4" name="height1">
                        <select class="bmi_txtbx" name="height1uom">
                            <option selected="" value="ft">ft.</option>
                            <option value="m">m</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                    <span class="style3">
                    <input type="text" class="bmi_txtbx" size="4" name="height2">
                        <select class="bmi_txtbx" name="height2uom">
                            <option selected="" value="in">in.</option>
                            <option value="cm">cm</option>
                    </select>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="right">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <hr size="1" noshade="noshade" align="left" width="200">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <span class="style4">Your BMI is:</span>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="style3">
                    <input type="text" class="bmi_txtbx" size="5" name="bmi">
                    </span>
                    <span class="style3">
                    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateBMI()" name="button">
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Reset">
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>

</table>
```

Please help me solve this problem, any idea will very helpful for me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are available inside an iframe so You need to switch to iframe first to access the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`()
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `elementToBeClickable`() and use the following Xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='/Content/id-ID/html/Herbalife/standalone/BMI.html']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='weight' and @class='bmi_txtbx']"))).sendKeys("200");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='height1' and @class='bmi_txtbx']"))).sendKeys("4");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='height2' and @class='bmi_txtbx']"))).sendKeys("22");
```

Comment: still have the same problem, and ```org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@name='weight' and @class='bmi_txtbx'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)```

Comment: @jhon : Check if there any iframe on your page source.

Comment: yes that form is iFrame, I see it in console, BMI.html (iFrame)

Comment: Can you post that iframe html tag.because you need to switch this iframe first as i mentioned on my answer.

Comment: just go to top of the page and search iframe and post that html.

Comment: I don't know about iframe, but inside my console
the html iframe name is BMI.html

if it's wrong, can you give an example like iframe html tag, because i don't know how to write from my console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204804/discussion-between-kunduk-and-jhon).